Understanding CPU allocation in Hyper-V with Intel Xeon Silver 4214R
I’m seeking insights into CPU allocation in Hyper-V, specifically related to my current hardware configuration and how best to optimize resource allocation for my virtual machines (VMs).
Hardware Overview:

CPU Model: Intel Xeon Silver 4214R
Cores:  24
Logical Processors: 48

Current Configuration:
I have prepared two VMs with the following allocations:

VM1: Allocated: 8 CPU Cores
VM2: Allocated: 28 CPU Cores

Hardware Overview screenshot

My Questions:
I've allocated more CPU Cores to my Hyper-V virtual machine than my physical server has available cores. Hyper-V does support overcommitting CPU resources (assigning more virtual CPUs than there are physical cores) but how does it work?

With a total of 48 logical processors, my vCPU allocation results in an overcommitment ratio of 75%. Is this generally acceptable, and what potential issues should I be aware of?

How can I effectively align vCPU allocations with NUMA nodes to optimize performance? Given that I have two CPUs, should I allocate vCPUs in multiples of 12 to match the physical cores?

Are there specific best practices or recommendations for configuring vCPU allocations for varying workloads, especially for CPU-intensive applications?

Should I consider disabling Hyper-Threading for specific VMs to improve performance, or is it beneficial to keep it enabled for most workloads?


I appreciate any insights, experiences, or resources you can share regarding managing CPU resources effectively in a Hyper-V environment.
